# Excel VBA Web Scrape - getElementsbyTagName.Item Number isn't Constant

Tags: html, vba, excel, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I've trying to web-scrape County, Population and Median Home Value using the following VBA code below. This works, but I'm encountering the following problem: **The Item numbers (on block quotes below) vary, which means that for certain zip codes, I retrieve incorrect data points, see spreadsheet image below.**

[image]

I've researched for variable Item numbers, but the only case that comes close is retrieving a [collection](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/scrape-website-html.htm), then picking out the element by class name. However, the HTML I'm working with doesn't have a class name, see below:

Is it possible to first *find* the string "County: " and then retrieve the *innerText* of *TagName* *td*? I've also considered returning the entire table, but the data are hosted within two different tables. As you can see, I have some ideas, but can't seem to find a good example to go off of, so I'm kinda lost on the code aspect of it.

[image]

```
Sub ZipCodeScrape()

Set ZipCodeRange = Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = New InternetExplorer

Dim url As String
url = "https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/"

Dim County As String
Dim Population As String
Dim MedianHomeVal As String
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument

For Each cell In ZipCodeRange

    IE.navigate (url & cell.Value)

    'Allows IE to load
    While IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set HTMLdoc = IE.document

    County = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(2).innerText  
    Population = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(6).innerText  
    MedianHomeVal = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(12).innerText

    cell.Offset(0, 1) = County
    cell.Offset(0, 2) = Population
    cell.Offset(0, 3) = MedianHomeVal

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Use a data query to import page to a blank sheet then use cell references to access the data. `Alt + D, D, W`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. It will fetch you the expected output (county, population and median home value). I've set there few search options taken from your uploaded image. Btw, the search should be made with zip code otherwise the `population` and `median home value` doesn't show up in that webpage.

```
Sub ZipCodeScrape()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim search_input As Variant, posts As Object, post As Object, elem As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/"
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document
    End With

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")

    For Each search_input In [{"32937","33056","33312","33844","34698"}]

        html.getElementById("q").Value = search_input
        html.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-danger")(0).Click
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

        For Each posts In html.getElementsByTagName("th")
            If InStr(posts.innerText, "County:") > 0 Then Row = Row + 1: Cells(Row, 1) = posts.NextSibling.innerText: Exit For
        Next posts
        For Each post In html.getElementsByTagName("th")
            If InStr(post.innerText, "Population") > 0 Then Cells(Row, 2) = post.ParentNode.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText: Exit For
        Next post
        For Each elem In html.getElementsByTagName("th")
            If InStr(elem.innerText, "Median Home Value") > 0 Then Cells(Row, 3) = elem.ParentNode.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText: Exit For
        Next elem
    Next search_input
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've refactored your post to the following:         For Each post In HTML.getElementsByTagName("th")
            If InStr(post.innerText, "County:") > 0 Then
            County = post.NextSibling.innerText
            If InStr(post.innerText, "Population") > 0 Then
            Population = post.NextSibling.innerText
            If InStr(post.innerText, "Median Home Value") > 0 Then
            MedianHomeVal = post.NextSibling.innerText: Exit For           Next post

Comment: I get a 438 error once it finds population. I've tried declaring it as long and retrieving NextSibling.Value but it didn't work; NextSibling.NodeValue doesn't work. This other user is having the same issue in this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688478/how-to-read-a-ie-table-text-with-vba (see the comments on the answer). He didn't get a reply though. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your requirement was to find the county as landmark and get it's value. Are you not getting that? Be specific.

Comment: County is coming through fine. However, I also need population and median home value, specified when I posted the question. I figured I could you the methodology in your answer for pop and median home value but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: See the edited code. It will fetch you all the required items you have requested. Next time be a little bit specific about your  search parameter and how it works. I tried with `county` names as search input for the first time and looked for the values you wanted but the `population` and `median home value` was not there. Go to that page make a search with county name and see for yourself what happens. Btw, if it helps don't forget to press the upvote button and tick the grayed out checkmark next to my answer to accept it as your selected answer. Thanks.

Comment: Good answer as usual. Couldn't find a more reliable way :-(

Answer (score 2):

Maybe loop through `<th>` elements and then get the [next sibling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.nextsibling(v=vs.110).aspx) node which should be the desired td node? I have not tested this.

```
For each header in HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("th")
    If header.InnerText = "County: " then
        county = header.NextSibling.InnerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that when the search is "County","County:" etc instead of "County: " then it fails miserably. That means it only works when your search string and the one located in the web is exactly identical. In fact a variation of leading or ending space will break the code.